# Большинство .. предназначено / предназначены

Tags: грамматика, согласование, глаголы, единственное-множественное-число

Как будет правильно и почему?

> Большинство номеров **предназначено** для некурящих.
>   Большинство номеров **предназначены** для некурящих.

Я бы смело выбрал вариант **предназначено**, но заметил большую вариативность в использовании. На самом деле, для меня два варианта звучат хорошо.

Вот некоторые выдерки из книг/статей:

> Большинство седативных средств **предназначены** для перераспределения адреналина.
>   Большинство проектов было **предназначено** для женщин и девочек неголландского происхождения.
>   ... большинство оценок **предназначено** для содействия разработке ...
>   Большинство таких программ **предназначено** для уменьшения ...
>   Большинство из них **предназначены** для использования в тех предметных областях, к которым они относятся.
>   большинство кассетных боеприпасов **предназначены** для разброса больших количеств суббоеприпасов по обширному району.

ну и так далее

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А нам разрешён выбор.

**[Согласование сказуемого со словами  «ряд, большинство, меньшинство, часть, множество»](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo)**

Выбор правильной формы сказуемого осложняется тем, что опорное слово подлежащего (ряд, большинство, множество и т. п.), представляя собой существительное в форме единственного числа,  фактически означает множество предметов или явлений как совокупность. В этой связи появляются две возможности для согласования сказуемого:

- **формально-грамматическое согласование:** сказуемое принимает такую же грамматическую форму, как и подлежащее; большинство граждан проголосовало за нового президента («большинство» и «проголосовало» – единственное число, средний род); ряд пользователей отказался от платной услуги («ряд» и «отказался» – единственное число, мужской род);
- **согласование по смыслу:** сказуемое принимает форму множественного числа, поскольку подлежащее обозначает множество предметов или явлений: большинство граждан проголосовали за нового президента, ряд пользователей отказались от платной услуги.
  В современном русском языке формально-грамматическое согласование сказуемого и согласование по смыслу конкурируют, и в большинстве случаев (но не всегда!) формы единственного и множественного числа сказуемого взаимозаменяемы.

Формальное согласование рода и числа сказуемого требуется, если собирательное существительное не имеет при себе зависимых слов, а также если в составе подлежащего нет существительных в форме множественного числа: За принятие постановления проголосовало большинство, меньшинство было против; Подавляющее большинство парламента проголосовало против принятия закона; Часть населения безграмотна.

**Согласование по смыслу предпочтительно:**

1) если между подлежащим и сказуемым располагаются другие члены предложения: Множество замечаний по содержанию диссертации и оформлению библиографии были высказаны молодому аспиранту;

2) если при подлежащем имеется последующее определение в форме множественного числа, выраженное причастным оборотом или придаточным предложением со словом которые: Часть средств, вырученных от продажи книги, пойдут на содержание больниц; Часть средств, которые будут выручены от продажи книг, пойдут на содержание больниц;

3) если нужно подчеркнуть раздельность действий каждого действующего лица, называемого подлежащим, а также подчеркнуть активность действующих лиц: Ряд сотрудников нашей организации выступили с инициативой; ср.: В прошлом году было построено множество дорог.

4) если сказуемых – несколько: Ряд учеников не считают выполнение домашних заданий необходимым и приходят на урок неподготовленными.

5) если в составе сказуемого есть существительное или прилагательное в форме множественного числа: Большинство домов в этой деревне были деревянными.

Comment: А как же все-таки быть с номерами для некурящих (см. вопрос)?

Comment: Так как выбор нам дан, предпочитаю в данном случае формально-грамматическое согласование: ***Большинство номеров предназначено для некурящих.***